# Data from central is received only every 10 seconds, why?

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

The peripheral is set up to advertise with one service, which two characteristics are added to. One characteristic has the property notify and the permission readable. The other characteristic has the property write and the permission writable. The second mentioned characteristic is used for the communication from the central to the peripheral and that is where the issue is.

It seems that there is 10 second cycle. Never more than one of the expected packages can be received more then once in a time span of 10 seconds. Also if the central sends data 10 seconds after it has sent data before the peripheral receives the expected package instantly, less than a second.

You can see what I mean with the output from the debugger.

[image: Every 4 seconds data is trying to be sent to peripheral.]

**Edited Feb 15 2017**  *
To clarify this issue a bit better I will give more information about the output from the debugger. What you see here is the central being debugged. The wording "writeValue" indicates that the data was sent and the wording "didWriteValueFor" indicates the confirmation that the data had reached the peripheral successfully. This confirmation is called in the delegate method:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?)
```

*

It is as if the communication in the described direction is blocked for 10 seconds after last reception of data and then opened again. Is it possible to prevent this blocking?  The peripheral(s) need(s) to be informed instantly and not only every 10 seconds. I am sure I am configuring something wrong or I have forgotten something essential.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear from your description whether you are connected to the peripheral or just relying on advertising events. Advertising events are low duty cycle and 10.25 seconds is the max cycle time. Most peripherals advertise at rates approaching this max for power conservation.

Comment: They are connected. I did not mention that the peripheral and central are connected, because it is not known to me that the central can pass on data to the peripheral when not connected. Thank you for the info on the advertisement's 10 seconds low duty cycle.

Comment: What's your device's connection interval? That's going to determine how often you can communicate with the device. (I don't know of any way to get this through CoreBluetooth; you generally get it by knowing how you've configured the firmware on the peripheral. It may be available via IOBluetooth, but I've never tried that on iOS.)

Comment: I am not sure what the device’s connections interval is. It would be interesting to know how to figure that out. Nevertheless I was able to solve the problem, I did not need to dig too deep. It was simply a configuration change I had to make. The basic configuration change I did is “withResponse” to “withoutResponse”. I will answer more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last the data transfer from iOS central to iOS peripheral reaches a decent speed. To achieve this there were two changes I had to make, they are directly linked with each other. On the iOS peripheral side as on the iOS central side the changes were made.
Part of the solution is the configuration of the CBMutableCharacteristic object on the iOS peripheral side. I had set it’s properties to Writable With Response, though to make communication as fast as I need it , I now set it to Writable Without Response.
So the instantiation of the CBMutableCharacteristic object looks like this:

```
let characteristicWritableWithoutResponseCBMutableCharacteristic.init(type: CBUUID.init(string: TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID), properties: CBCharacteristicProperties.writeWithoutResponse, value: nil, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.writeable)
```

The other part of the solution is on the central’s side. Since the CBMutableCharacteristic object is instantiated with “writeWithoutResponse” I had to change the parameter type for the method writeValue from CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse to 
CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse. This looks like this now:

```
currentPeripheral.writeValue(newPayload, for: writableCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)
```

The time for data transfer from central to peripheral is now well under one second. Though I must mention the central sends very little data (originally a value of datatype double).
I hope this will help others too.